# Incorrect rendering for Khmer using LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec

When I compile the following MWE with XeLaTeX, it works pretty fine. But when I compile with LuaLaTeX some Khmer vowels are missing.

Does LuaLaTeX support Khmer Unicode? Or is this a problem caused by fontspec? Or is there any additional package fixing this issue? I am new to LuaLaTeX. [Here](http://www.khmeros.info/en/fonts) is a Khmer font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\newfontfamily\khmerfont[Script=Khmer]{Khmer OS}
\newcommand{\textkh}[1]{\begingroup\khmerfont#1\endgroup}
\begin{document}
    Compile this with \XeLaTeX{} to see the correct rendering.
    \par
    \textkh{តើមានអ្វីប្លែក?}
    \par
    When compile with Lua\LaTeX{} \textkh{ើ} becames \textkh{ី}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like a problem in luaotfload. Make a bug report (but the support of this scripts imho isn't perfect yet).